# Someone is keep calling my api services via node.js load test

Tags: apache, rest, cpanel, whm

I have a VPS hosted on Softlayer. Some idiot is keep on calling api service via node.js load test making almost 50 api calls / second.

It is slowing down my server. IP of the attacker is 35.193.63.213. It is itself a node.js api tester.

Any help would be appreciable

Comment: Contact the hosting provider and report them the IP, they might block it.

Comment: @this.lau_ I have contacted them. IP has been also blocked but still it is continuously calling the api. What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

If your API is supposed no to be public, just add CORS Crossdomain restriction to your nodejs app.

first install CORS module:

```
npm install cors
```

then for example using express, configure CORS to allow access just to the same domain where the service is hosted or the domain that's supposed to access to the API.

```
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

var corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://example.com',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204 
}

app.get('/products/:id', cors(corsOptions), function (req, res, next) {
  res.json({msg: 'This is CORS-enabled for only example.com.'})
})

app.listen(80, function () {
  console.log('CORS-enabled web server listening on port 80')
})
```